# How did I start getting this warning in Rails, without changing anything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, warnings, deprecated

This morning I started getting the following warning when running tests.

`DEPRECATION WARNING: <% %> style block helpers are deprecated. Please use <%= %>.`

I can see how to fix the warning.

How is it possible to start to get a warning without changing any code or updating any gems?

Working in Rails 3, Ruby 1.92.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [section 7.4.2 of the Rails 3.0 release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#action-view), `<%=` is the standard for helpers that insert content. So, you must've had the deprecation warning when using a Rails 3 application according to the documentation, but perhaps you never noticed it.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Someone else modified the file last week.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you switched rvm environments and got a completely different set of gems?